# Why the JSP Page encoding directive should be the first line in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I mean the following directive

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

I have lots of JSPs. I wrote this line in a common file that was already included in all JSPs. But that didn't help, I could see browser using different encoding than what I specified in above directive.

I had to manually wrote that directive as the first line to solve the problem.

I am asking this question in context of problem raised in [this article](http://cagan327.blogspot.com/2006/05/utf-8-encoding-fix-tomcat-jsp-etc.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that anything that comes before that directive will have its output to be written to the output stream that goes towards the browser - and the encoding specifies how that stream translates the String content of the page to bytes, so it must be set when the stream is created, *before* anything is written to it.

Comment: yeah i agree but in the common file i used ,@page encoding was the first line. and i wrote the include directive to include the common file in every jsp as first line. so before that directive was encountered nothing was sent to the client (needing an encoding translation)

Answer (score -1):

how else would the Java runtime know the file is a JSP and thus to compile and handle it as such, rather than as plain text to be just pushed to the client?

Comment: The contentType page directive has absolutely nothing to do with how the JSP container decides which files to compile as JSPs.